In C#, does it matter the order of types when it comes to using the "is" keyword?
I know that the is operator in C# is used for type checking and I read on Microsoft Learn that it checks if the types are compatible.
What exactly does 'compatible' mean here?
Does it mean both types are in the same inheritance hierarchy?
If so, does it matter if the type written before the is operator is parent to the one written after it or the opposite?
What about interfaces? Does it also matter if the implementing class is written before the is operator or after it in relevant to the interface name?
Suppose we have two classes A and B, B inherits from A and B also implements IBable interface:
public interface IBable { }

public class A { }

public class B: A, IBable { }

Which one of those expressions will return true and which one will return false?
public void TestIs ()
{
   A a = new A();
   B b = new B();

   Console.WriteLine(a is B);
   Console.WriteLine(b is A);
   Console.WriteLine(b is IBable);
}

Also, one more question, can the is operator be used with any object of any class/struct or should one of the operands be of the Type class (returned by the typeof() operator)?

a is b won’t compile; the right-hand operand must be a typename or a constant.

The first thing to do would be to (try to) run your own code; it would immediately answer half of your questions.

public A a; still not valid...you can't use public keyword in local variables definition...

The exact meaning of "compatible" is given in the documentation

E is T

where E is an expression that returns a value and T is the name of a  type or a type parameter. E can't be an anonymous method or a lambda  expression.
The is operator returns true when an expression result is non-null and
any of the following conditions are true:

The run-time type of an expression result is T.

The run-time type of an expression result derives from type T, implements interface T, or another implicit reference conversion
exists from it to T.

The run-time type of an expression result is a nullable value type with the underlying type T and the Nullable.HasValue is true.

A boxing or unboxing conversion exists from the run-time type of an expression result to type T.


The is operator doesn't consider user-defined conversions.

(emphasis is mine)
So to answer your questions:

Does it mean both types are in the same inheritance hierarchy? If so, does it matter if the type written before the is operator is parent to the one written after it or the opposite?

It's not enough that they are in the same hirarchy. The first must be derived from the second.

What about interfaces?

If the first implements the interface, the is operator will return true.

Does it also matter if the implementing class is written before the is operator or after it in relevant to the interface name?

Yes, it matter. The interface must be the second one.
Therefore if you run the program:
using System;

public interface IBable { }
public class A { }
public class B : A, IBable { }

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A a = new A();
        B b = new B();

        Console.WriteLine(a is B);      // False because A is not derived from B
        Console.WriteLine(b is A);      // True  because B is derived from A
        Console.WriteLine(b is IBable); // True  because B implements IBable
    }
}

The output will be:
False
True
True

Live demo

I think you are looking for this documentation.
E is T


where E is an expression that returns a value and T is the name of a
type or a type parameter.
The is operator returns true when an expression result is non-null
and any of the following conditions are true:

The run-time type of an expression result is T.
The run-time type of an expression result derives from type T, implements interface T, or another implicit reference conversion
exists from it to T.
...


E is value of a type, T is name of a type.
A a = new() -> value of type A (E)
A -> name of type (T)
Knowing this you can see how your question is wrongly formulated, we don't have two types, we have a value and a type name.
If so, does it matter if the type written before the is operator is parent to the one written after it or the opposite?
So get rid of typeof(T) in your example (which won't compile anyway) and just use the name of the type, i.e. a is A.
The relevance of order in your question then can be summed as:
Are
b is A;

and
a is B; 

the same.
No, they are not.
Also make note that you have variables that are not set to anything. Try experimenting with setting them to null and then to new() to fully acknowledge the differences as noted in the bolded parts from the documentation about the value being null or not.
A a = null;
B b = null;

Console.WriteLine(a is A); // False
Console.WriteLine(a is B); // False
Console.WriteLine(a is IBable); // False
Console.WriteLine();

Console.WriteLine(b is A); // False
Console.WriteLine(b is B); // False
Console.WriteLine(b is IBable); // False
Console.WriteLine();

a = new();
b = new();

Console.WriteLine(a is A); // True
Console.WriteLine(a is B); // False
Console.WriteLine(a is IBable); // False
Console.WriteLine();

Console.WriteLine(b is A); // True
Console.WriteLine(b is B); // True
Console.WriteLine(b is IBable); // True


I remember there was another similar functionality where you have to use the 'typeof()' operator, is it when you want to compare the return value of 'GetType()' method?

yes, a is A is similar but not the same as a.GetType() == typeof(A), a is typeof(A) is apples and oranges as suggested by the text of the compilation error you will get: CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Type' to 'A'
